# Use data allocated dynamically in CUDA kernel on host

Tags: c++, cuda, dynamic-memory-allocation, memcpy

I am trying to build a container class on the device which manages some memory.
This memory is allocated dynamically and filled during object construction in the kernel. 
According to the documentation that can be done with a simple new[] in the kernel (using CUDA 8.0 with compute cabability 5.0 in Visual Studio 2012).
Afterwards I want to access the data inside the containers in host code (e.g. for testing if all values are correct).

A minimal version of the `DeviceContainer` class looks like this:

```
class DeviceContainer 
{
public:
   __device__ DeviceContainer(unsigned int size);
   __host__ __device__ ~DeviceContainer();

   __host__ __device__ DeviceContainer(const DeviceContainer & other);
   __host__ __device__ DeviceContainer & operator=(const DeviceContainer & other);

   __host__ __device__ unsigned int getSize() const { return m_sizeData; }
   __device__ int * getDataDevice() const { return mp_dev_data; }
   __host__ int* getDataHost() const;

private:
   int * mp_dev_data;
   unsigned int m_sizeData;
};


__device__ DeviceContainer::DeviceContainer(unsigned int size) :
      m_sizeData(size), mp_dev_data(nullptr) 
{
   mp_dev_data = new int[m_sizeData];

   for(unsigned int i = 0; i < m_sizeData; ++i) {
      mp_dev_data[i] = i;
   }
}


__host__ __device__ DeviceContainer::DeviceContainer(const DeviceContainer & other) : 
  m_sizeData(other.m_sizeData)
{
#ifndef __CUDA_ARCH__
   cudaSafeCall( cudaMalloc((void**)&mp_dev_data, m_sizeData * sizeof(int)) );
   cudaSafeCall( cudaMemcpy(mp_dev_data, other.mp_dev_data, m_sizeData * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice) );
#else
   mp_dev_data = new int[m_sizeData];
   memcpy(mp_dev_data, other.mp_dev_data, m_sizeData * sizeof(int));
#endif
}


__host__ __device__ DeviceContainer::~DeviceContainer()
{
#ifndef __CUDA_ARCH__
   cudaSafeCall( cudaFree(mp_dev_data) );
#else
   delete[] mp_dev_data;
#endif
   mp_dev_data = nullptr;
}


__host__ __device__ DeviceContainer & DeviceContainer::operator=(const DeviceContainer & other)
{
   m_sizeData = other.m_sizeData;

 #ifndef __CUDA_ARCH__
   cudaSafeCall( cudaMalloc((void**)&mp_dev_data, m_sizeData * sizeof(int)) );
   cudaSafeCall( cudaMemcpy(mp_dev_data, other.mp_dev_data, m_sizeData * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice) );
#else
   mp_dev_data = new int[m_sizeData];
   memcpy(mp_dev_data, other.mp_dev_data, m_sizeData * sizeof(int));
#endif

   return *this;
}


__host__ int* DeviceContainer::getDataHost() const
{
   int * pDataHost = new int[m_sizeData];
   cudaSafeCall( cudaMemcpy(pDataHost, mp_dev_data, m_sizeData * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );
   return pDataHost;
}
```

It just manages the array `mp_dev_data`. 
The array is created and filled with consecutive values during construction, which should only be possible on the device. (Note that in reality the size of the containers might be different from each other.)

I think I need to provide a copy constructor and an assignment operator since I don't know any other way to fill the array in the kernel. (See question No. 3 below.)
Since copy and deletion can also happen on the host, `__CUDA_ARCH__` is used to determine for which execution path we're compiling. On the host `cudaMemcpy` and `cudaFree` is used, on the device we can just use `memcpy` and `delete[]`.

The kernel for object creation is rather simple:

```
__global__ void createContainer(DeviceContainer * pContainer, unsigned int numContainer, unsigned int containerSize)
{
   unsigned int offset = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

   if(offset < numContainer)
   {
      pContainer[offset] = DeviceContainer(containerSize);
   }
}
```

Each thread in a one-dimensional grid that is in range creates a single container object.

The main-function then allocates arrays for the container (90000 in this case) on the device and host, calls the kernel and attempts to use the objects:

```
void main()
{
   const unsigned int numContainer = 90000;
   const unsigned int containerSize = 5;

   DeviceContainer * pDevContainer;
   cudaSafeCall( cudaMalloc((void**)&pDevContainer, numContainer * sizeof(DeviceContainer)) );

   dim3 blockSize(1024, 1, 1);
   dim3 gridSize((numContainer + blockSize.x - 1)/blockSize.x , 1, 1);

   createContainer<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(pDevContainer, numContainer, containerSize);
   cudaCheckError();

   DeviceContainer * pHostContainer = (DeviceContainer *)malloc(numContainer * sizeof(DeviceContainer)); 
   cudaSafeCall( cudaMemcpy(pHostContainer, pDevContainer, numContainer * sizeof(DeviceContainer), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );

   for(unsigned int i = 0; i < numContainer; ++i)
   {
      const DeviceContainer & dc = pHostContainer[i];

      int * pData = dc.getDataHost();
      for(unsigned int j = 0; j < dc.getSize(); ++j)
      {
         std::cout << pData[j];
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;
      delete[] pData;
   }

   free(pHostContainer);
   cudaSafeCall( cudaFree(pDevContainer) );
}
```

I have to use `malloc` for array creation on the host, since i don't want to have a default constructor for the `DeviceContainer`.
I try to access the data inside a container via `getDataHost()` which internally just calls `cudaMemcpy`.

`cudaSafeCall` and `cudaCheckError` are simple macros that evaluate the `cudaError` returned by the function oder actively poll the last error. For the sake of completeness:

```
#define cudaSafeCall(error) __cudaSafeCall(error, __FILE__, __LINE__)
#define cudaCheckError()    __cudaCheckError(__FILE__, __LINE__)

inline void __cudaSafeCall(cudaError error, const char *file, const int line)
{
   if (error != cudaSuccess)
   {
      std::cerr << "cudaSafeCall() returned:" << std::endl;
      std::cerr << "\tFile: " << file << ",\nLine: " << line << " - CudaError " << error << ":" << std::endl;
      std::cerr << "\t" << cudaGetErrorString(error) << std::endl;

      system("PAUSE");
      exit( -1 );
   }
}


inline void __cudaCheckError(const char *file, const int line)
{
   cudaError error = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
   if (error != cudaSuccess)
   {
      std::cerr << "cudaCheckError() returned:" << std::endl;
      std::cerr << "\tFile: " << file << ",\tLine: " << line << " - CudaError " << error << ":" << std::endl;
      std::cerr << "\t" << cudaGetErrorString(error) << std::endl;

      system("PAUSE");
      exit( -1 );
   }
}
```

I have 3 problems with this code:

1. If it is executed as presented here i recieve an "unspecified launch failure" of the kernel. The Nsight Debugger stops me on the line `mp_dev_data = new int[m_sizeData];` (either in the constructor or the assignment operator) and reports several access violation on global memory. The number of violations appears to be random between 4 and 11 and they occur in non-consecutive threads but always near the upper end of the grid (block 85 and 86).
2. If i reduce `numContainer` to 10, the kernel runs smoothly, however, the `cudaMamcpy` in `getDataHost()` fails with an invalid argument error - even though `mp_dev_data` is not 0. (I suspect that the assignment is faulty and the memory has already been deleted by another object.)
3. Even though I would like to know how to correctly implement the `DeviceContainer` with proper memory management, in my case it would also be sufficient to make it non-copyable and non-assignable. However, I don't know how to properly fill the container-array in the kernel. Maybe something like

   `DeviceContainer dc(5);
   memcpy(&pContainer[offset], &dc, sizeof(DeviceContainer));`

   Which would lead to problems with deleting `mp_dev_data` in the destructor. I would need to manually manage memory deletion which feels rather dirty.

I also tried to use `malloc` and `free` in kernel code instead of `new` and `delete` but the results were the same.

I am sorry that I wasn't able to frame my question in a shorter manner.

TL;DR: How to implement a class that dynamically allocates memory in a kernel and can also be used in host code? How can I initialize an array in a kernel with objects that can not be copied or assigned?

Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the answer is: What I am trying to do is more or less impossible.
Memory allocated with `new` or `malloc` in the kernel is not placed in global memory but rather in a special heap memory which is inaccessible from the host.

The only option to access all memory on the host is to first allocate an array in global memory which is big enough to hold all elements on the heap and then write a kernel that copies all elements from the heap to global memory.

The access violation are caused by the limited heap size (which can be changed by `cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimitMallocHeapSize, size_t size)`.